# How to input a variable to use in a function

Tags: javascript, list, function

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm a javascript noob

I'm trying to specify a list to find a random entry in. How can I do this without using if/else statements or switches?

```js
var one = ["Japan","Vietnam","Korea"]
var two = ["bleghg","djakd","dasda"]
var three = ["woop","doop","loop"]

function randomItem (list) {
    return list[Math.random()*list.length]
  }
```

this is a simplification of what I'm trying to do, where I would input the name of an existing list (one, two, or three) and it would get a random item from that list

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Where are you getting the name from? Can't you just directly pass the variable?

Answer (score 1):

To access a random position in the list, you need to generate a random number against the list length and then round it, like below. No condition testing required.

```
list[Math.floor(Math.random()*list.length)];
```

To use this with your code then you would call your function with one of your lists as a parameter. Like so:

```
console.log(randomItem(one));
```

Comment: That fixes their code but doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `list` param in the function with the name of the list:

```
randomItem(one)
```

```js
var one = ["Japan", "Vietnam", "Korea"]
var two = ["bleghg", "djakd", "dasda"]
var three = ["woop", "doop", "loop"]

function randomItem(list) {
  // you need to round the random number down
  return list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length, 10)];
}

var result = randomItem(one);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since @Thomas Juranek has corrected your use of Math.random for you, I won't dwell into that. Instead, I will answer your question on retrieving variable using variable names.

I would call this a hack, but variables declared in global are bound to the window object. If you are passing variable name only, you can retrieve it by doing the following:

```
function getWindowObject(variableName) {
  return window[variableName];
}
```

It definitely makes more sense to just pass the variable, however. A slightly better way to do this, if you insist on wanting to declare loosely hanging variables outside the function scope, would be to wrap it in an object:

```
var myPersonalScope = {};
myPersonalScope["one"] = [1, 2, 3];
myPersonalScope["two"] = [4, 5, 6];

function getPersonalScopeObject(variableName) {
  return myPersonalScope[variableName];
}
```